# Community rejected my edit after OP copied my edit

Tags: discussion

So I edited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49936972/i-am-migrating-db-oracle-to-postgresql-and-i-found-some-issue-with-this-query#49936972) formatting the code in the question as OP had pasted it in plain text, and I had left the question open in a different tab, I just returned to that tab and saw that there was an edit for me to load, so immediately I thought, wow that suggestion actually went through quick, loaded the edit, but I wasn't given credit for it even though the edit was identical to what I suggested, even the edit comment was the same, so I went to my suggestions on my profile to see why my edit was rejected to see that it was rejected by the community because it conflicted with a newer edit (which was actually my edit). [My edit in the review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19495505)

What action should I take here? Should I confront the OP in the question?

Comment: Seems like it's by-design. It's highly unlikely that OP would know this would happen. Don't worry about it, there are no automated edit suggestion bans and once you reach 2k rep your edits wouldn't need to go through review.

Comment: @SamuelLiew I understand that it would be by design, I guess I was mainly asking how to proceed with the situation

Comment: Forgive and forget I suppose... OP isn't really to blame here

Comment: I don't think there is anything to do. There is a reason why OP has final say on their post. This is probably just a new user who didn't know much about the system.

Comment: See no Evil! Perhaps Op find your edit really cool and wanted to add more. But wasnt satisfy about anything that he could had. He rejected your edit because he wanted to post a better one and failed.

Comment: anyway only ~700 more to go till this will cease to matter

Comment: @SurajRao yeah I'm close, I just don't have the required knowledge to answer the obscure questions, and often I am beaten to the mark posting the answer, but i'll get there eventually

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Same thing just happened to me and I was on a [23 no-reject edit streak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9614249/increasingly-idiotic?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). Feels bad man. =P